# [Android studio]How to set a new phone in Android 6.0? USB device not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, usb-drive

I bought a new phone, it's a "wiko Lenny 3". I'm trying to configure my Android Studio to debug my apps on it.

I put my phone on the usb debug on, i set the screen to always active, i activated the unlock oem, and for the fictive position it asks me what's the app I want to set, I have only one choice: the radio. It was strange but I set it.

I downloaded the drivers but my computer doesn't want to install them. So I installed them on the folder "usb-drivers" in android-studio.

I don't know what's going wrong, I searched a lot on the internet but I didn't find anything useful.

Maybe I have to download good drivers but I don't know how to find them, the official website doesnt have the drivers.

PS: the android version is a special version create by wiko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all download the Google USB Driver[image]
Then open to Device Manager. You will find our device name under other devices.
Right click on that and select **Update Driver Software..**

Then select **Browse my computer for software driver**
after that select **Let me pick**
then select **Android Device**
finally select **Android ADB Interface**
click next and install it.

Note: Make sure you enable Developers Options and USB debugging.
It should work like charm.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to enable debugging in phone's settings - enable developer mode first and then allow debugging, maybe that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

First u need to install drivers for phone, next step is enable debugging mode in phone. And next u will easy connect and android studio will find a phone

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems with connecting my new Huawei Nova with Android Studio (on Windows 7). Maybe it helps you.

1. Download USB driver for your phone - I found drivers for Huawei Nova [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-huawei-usb-drivers)
2. Enable "Developer mode" and "USB debugging" your on phone - I found information how to do it [here](https://how2phone.com/20497/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-on-huawei-nova)
3. Open "Device manager" and find your device. In my case it was in "Other devices" section as "ADB Interface"
4. Right-clik and choose "Update Driver Software"
5. Select "Browse for driver softwere on your computer" and then "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
6. From the list of device types select "Show All Devices" (first option on the top) and click "Next"
7. In "Select the driver..." window select "Have disk" and find your driver on your PC. You have to select setup information file (.inf), then click "OK"
8. Select "Android ADB Interface" and click "Next" to install it.

P.S. In step 8 I've got warning that windows can't verify is this driver is compatible with the device, I click "Yes" and the driver was install properly.

After that Android Studio sees my Huawei Nova.

---

UPDATE (for Windows 10):

1. Download USB driver for your phone - I found drivers for Huawei Nova [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-huawei-usb-drivers)
2. Enable "Developer mode" and "USB debugging" your on phone - I found information how to do it [here](https://how2phone.com/20497/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-on-huawei-nova)
3. Open "Device manager", choose "Action" tab and click "Add legacy hardware"
4. New window will pop-up ("Welcome to the Add Hardware Wizard"), click Next
5. Choose option "Install the hardware tha I manually selected from a list (Advanced)", click Next
6. Choose "Show All Devices" and click Next
7. Click "Have a disk" and find downloaded driver on your PC. You have to select setup information file (.inf), then click "OK"
8. From list (Model) choose "Android ADB Interface" and finish installation
9. Restart Android Stuido and your phone should be visible as AVD device

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **developer mode**. 
Find the Android Build Number in settings

*Settings > About phone > Build number*

Once you’ve found the Build number section of the settings, tap on the section 7 times. After two taps, a small pop up notification should appear saying "you are now X steps away from being a developer" with a number that counts down with every additional tap. 
After the 7th tap, the Developer options will be unlocked and available. They can usually be found in the main settings menu. You dive into that menu to do things like enable USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have the device drivers installed in your system for your device.
2. Allow USB debugging in your device.

   First, Developers Options should be enabled in your device, then

   Settings > Developers Options > USB Debugging(enable)

3.Connect your device as a Camera

Answer (score 0):

I have the Google USB driver installed, my phone is already unlock, the usb debugging is enable on my phone too.
I'll try to find a way to install this drivers one more time and let you know.
Thank's everybody

Answer (score 0):

My computer (windows 8) don't want to install driver without a licence but I find a way to do this on internet. Now it works fine.
Thank you =)